# Does GoCD checkout latest code from GitHub before every stage?

Tags: github, go-cd

I created a GoCD pipeline, in which i am using GitHub repository. I created two stages in this pipeline.

What happening is before every stage, it is taking the checkout of new code.

In second stage i don't want to checkout the github code, how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GoCD keeps the revision of all materials (including git repositories) stable within each pipeline instance.

This is true for separate stages as well as reruns of stages.

So under no circumstance will GoCD fetch the *lastet* version from GitHub in a second stage.

If you want to suppress the fetching of materials, you can set `fetchMaterials` to `false` in the `<stage>` tag:

```
<stage name="mySecondStage" fetchMaterials="false">
    ....
</stage>
```

Comment: Thx mortiz, it worked for me. Can you please also let me know, how to run two jobs in a single stage sequentially not parallel?

Comment: Jobs are designed to run parallel. If you need to run code sequentially, either use two tasks within a job, or two stages.